# CAS-Number available in Brightway2 for chemcial reference products of ecoinvent database?

Tags: brightway

In Brightway2, you can view the properties of an exchange with exchange.as_dict().
This dictionary contains a lot of information, which are also available on ecoinvent. Unfortunately, I can't find the CAS number as property. Is there a possibility to find the CAS numbers for the reference product of an activity, which are also stored in ecoinvent, in Brightway2?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

CAS numbers are available for biosphere flows when they are present:

```py
import bw2data as bd
b = bd.Database("biosphere3")
a = b.random()
a
>>> 'Fludioxonil' (kilogram, None, ('water', 'ground-'))
a['CAS number']
>>> '131341-86-1'
```

Are there CAS numbers for ecoinvent activities?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Ecoinvent also provides a CAS number for chemical technology flows. These are not found under "Exhange properties", but under "Reference product" or "From Technosphere".

Comment: Hi Stefan, So you could find them in BW2? I have been looking for them for a while. If you could detail your approach that would be great.